# Find the Center of Mass of Quadrilateral

Tags: vectors

I need to find the Center of Mass of Quadrilateral with vertex in points $$A(1;1;1;1)$$
$$B(2;3;4;5)$$
$$C(5;4;3;2)$$
$$D(7;8;9;10)$$

---

I've found information about triangle, but not about  Quadrilateral. And here we have 4D space. What is the algorithm?

Comment: Do you have equal masses at the four vertices, or mass uniformly distributed along the four (or six?) edges, or ...?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen it is said that polygon is made of homogeneous material. As I understand, it means that I have equal masses at the four vertices

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all your points have the same weight the center of mass (barycenter) is
$\left(\frac{1+2+5+7} 4, \frac{1+3+4+8} 4, \frac{1+4+3+9} 4, \frac{1+5+2+10} 4\right)$

Comment: Knowing that, can we say that given polygon is flat?

Comment: For example, center of mass is M. Built vectors MA,MB,MC,MD. Then build matrix of coordinates of these vectos. If det = 0 => all points (A,B,C,D) lie in the same plane. Is it correct?

Comment: I don't think so. the problem is you are in the 4D. if said det=0 that means that one of your vectors is a linear combination of the three others. in other terms the 4d volume of your quadrilateral is 0 (but that is true for all quadrilaterals). that does not mean that the 3d volume is 0 (which would imply that the quad is flat.

Comment: In order to show that it is indeed flat you have to write these vectors in terms of just two vectors

Comment: @НиколайЖурба One way to determine if it’s flat is to compute the nullity of $\small{\begin{bmatrix}A&1\\B&1\\C&1\\D&1\end{bmatrix}}$. For these points to be coplanar the null space must be at least two-dimensional.